# How do i get the csrf token from scenario 1 response using Karate framework?

Tags: karate

I have application api url which has passed as Background with Basicauth. Using that i need to get an csrf token. I tried with responsecookies. Nothing is coming up.

Can you please let me know how to get the csrf token from that specific api. I am getting actual application response but not the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation and go through the demo examples. It depends on the response. There are 2 possibilities, cookie (or header) OR the response body itself (plain text or JSON / XML).

So it is up to you to extract it and then store it as a variable, and use it to build headers for all future responses.

Please refer to the [demo example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/signin/sign-in.feature):

```
Given path 'signin', 'token'
When method get
Then status 200
And header X-CSRF-TOKEN = response
```

In this case, the token happened to be the entire `response` string.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the quick response.I tried the same but i don't know what value need to pass for the token and sign? Also there is no signin page as there is a sso app. What will have in the token? I tried it gets output as null.  function(creds) {
  var temp = creds.username + ':' + creds.password;
  var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
  var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.bytes);
  var token = karate.get('token');
  return 'Basic ' + encoded + token;
}

Comment: @user1980552 sorry I can't help you beyond this point. I think the best option is for you to talk to someone in your team, ideally someone who knows the details of the API on the server-side.

Comment: There is any gitter kind of community to have a direct chat?

Comment: In JS File passing function(creds) {
  var temp = creds.username + ':' + creds.password;
  var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
  var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.bytes);
  var token = karate.get('Cookie');
  return 'Basic ' + encoded + token;
}  In the feature Background:
* configure ssl = true
* header Authorization = call read('karate-config.js') {username: 'xxxxxx', password: 'xxxx'}
* header Accept = 'application/json'
* def uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }

Comment: Given path 'signin', 'token'
 When method GET
Then status 200
And header X-CSRF-TOKEN = response
* print 'csrf', X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: I am calling like above so i want to know how the signin and token values will be changed in my example?

Comment: @user1980552 I'm voting that this question be closed because it is not clear. also refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Can you please let me know whether we can get the cookies based on api end points?